# how can get only numbers from the text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get only the numbers(123) not the text(confirm), here is my code

```
<p>123confirm</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('p').click(function(){  
    var sd=$(this).text();  
    alert(sd);
  });
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `parseInt` for this, it will parse a string and remove any "junk" in it and return an integer.

As James Allardice noticed, the number must be before the string. So if it's the first thing in the text, it will work, else it won't.

-- EDIT -- Use with your example:

```
<p>123confirm</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('p').click(function(){  
    var sd=$(this).text();  
    sd=parseInt(sd);
    alert(sd);
  });
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Only if the number comes before any invalid characters (which is the case in the example). For example "confirm123" will return `NaN`.

Comment: No problem :) I guess it depends what the OP is actually trying to do... if the number will always be at start of the string, this is the best answer. If there will be numbers anywhere, separated by non-numeric characters, the regex answer will be better.

Answer (score 51):

I think a RegExp would be a good idea:

```js
var sd = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''); // Replace everything that is not a number with nothing
var number = parseInt(sd, 10); // Always hand in the correct base since 010 != 10 in js
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the regex itself, maybe you should use /[^0123456789]/gi - even better /\D/g

Comment: The regex in your answer should be fine, no need to specify each digit explicitly :)

Comment: WATCH out, negative integers get removed. For keeping negative values, you should use ´var sd = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\-]/gi, '');´

Comment: `myTryingString.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');`

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $(p).click(function(){  
    var sd=$(this).text();
    var num = sd.match(/[\d\.]+/g);
    if (num != null){
        var number = num.toString();
        alert(number );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Won't `var number = num.toString();` give a TypeError if the match fails?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this method:

```
 $('#totalseat').change(function() {
    var totalseat=$('#totalseat').val();
    var price=$('#seat_type option:selected').text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi,'');
    // Always hand in the correct base since 010 != 10 in js
    var price_int = parseInt(price,10);
    var total_price=parseInt(totalseat)*price_int;
    $('#totalprice').val(total_price);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex works for me also

```
var trdata = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
console.log(parseInt(trdata, 10));
```