# Find a number in a HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find

hello there my question is this:
it there a way to get a number out of an html code using jquery or javascript?

The code is this one:

```
<div class="issue-details">
<a href=/issues/3373"><img alt="Ticket" src="/images/ticket.png?1364554312">#3373</a>
Issue name - Issue description
</div>
```

The number i need to get is 3373 (number that changes, its not always the same!)

Anyone knows a way to get it out?

**EDIT**

I need to search for this number inside and HTMLLiElement, which i access using innerHTML.
Any suggestion on how i should use the parseInt on that?

Comment: `3373` from the `href` or from the text `#3373` ?

Comment: the number is always a link ?

Comment: Does your anchor text always start with the hash(#)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You final selector might differ but your code should be like this.

To read the attribute :

```
var num = parseInt($('.issue-details a').attr('href').split('/').pop(), 10);
```

To read the text content :

```
var num = parseInt($('.issue-details a').text().trim().slice(1), 10);
```

In the second one I use [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove potential spaces around the text and `slice(1)` to remove the `#`.

You might also want to search for your id using a regular expression :

```
var num = parseInt($('.issue-details').text().match(/#(\d+)/)[1], 10);
```

Comment: Now that's an unmaintainable but beautiful selector :)

Comment: the only problem is that i need to search for this string in something like this:
arguments[0].item[0].innerHTML, any suggestion?

Comment: If  you really need to search in this unparsed HTML string, then you may use `parseInt(arguments[0].item[0].innerHTML.match(/#(\d+)/)[1]), 10)`.

Comment: it works, and i got why it was not working :),
in your code in the comment parseInt(arguments[0].item[0].innerHTML.match(/#(\d+)/)[1]), 10) there is a **)** after [1] 

anyway, thank you, i solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
  parseInt($('.issue-details a').attr('href').split('/').pop(), 10);
```

also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357138/how-can-get-only-numbers-from-the-text-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get value of href attribute of needed anchor and then simply parse with javascript functions (for example split by '/' and take last part)